# Export a array of objects in a table with PHP in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have this array of objects that is looking like this:

```
Done:  array(2) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#107 (19) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "6"
["apartament"]=>
string(1) "1"
["nume"]=>
string(5) "SURCA"
["persoane"]=>
string(1) "2"
["mp"]=>
string(4) "37.7"
["retim"]=>
string(5) "19.19"
["incalzire"]=>
string(5) "74.74"
["apacaldamc"]=>
string(1) "3"
["apacaldalei"]=>
string(5) "47.48"
["apacaldadif"]=>
string(4) "3.72"
["aparecemc"]=>
string(1) "8"
["aparecelei"]=>
string(5) "54.73"
["aparecedif"]=>
NULL
["curent"]=>
string(3) "345"
["gaz"]=>
string(3) "2.5"
["administrator"]=>
string(5) "17.01"
["cheltuieliadministrare"]=>
string(4) "2.05"
["acoperis"]=>
string(4) "62.5"
["timp"]=>
string(19) "2017-04-28 10:04:28"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#108 (19) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "7"
["apartament"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nume"]=>
string(8) "ENACHIUC"
["persoane"]=>
string(1) "1"
["mp"]=>
string(5) "37.07"
["retim"]=>
string(3) "9.6"
["incalzire"]=>
string(4) "73.5"
["apacaldamc"]=>
string(1) "3"
["apacaldalei"]=>
string(5) "15.83"
["apacaldadif"]=>
string(4) "3.72"
["aparecemc"]=>
string(1) "2"
["aparecelei"]=>
string(5) "13.68"
["aparecedif"]=>
string(1) "0"
["curent"]=>
string(4) "0.66"
["gaz"]=>
string(4) "1.25"
["administrator"]=>
string(5) "17.01"
["cheltuieliadministrare"]=>
string(4) "2.05"
["acoperis"]=>
string(4) "62.5"
["timp"]=>
string(19) "2017-04-28 10:11:25"
}
}
```

I get this from a standard query:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM consum WHERE timp BETWEEN '".$fromDate."' AND '".$toDate."'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$databaseOject = $query->result();
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
if ($databaseOject->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><th>id</th><th>apartament</th><th>nume</th><th>apartament</th><th>persoane</th><th>mp</th><th>retim</th><th>incalzire</th><th>apacaldamc</th><th>apacaldalei</th><th>apacaldadif</th><th>aparecemc</th><th>aparecelei</th><th>aparecedif</th><th>curent</th><th>gaz</th><th>administrator</th><th>cheltuieliadministrare</th><th>acoperis</th><th>timp</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
        while($row = $databaseOject->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["apartament"]."</td><td>".$row["nume"]."</td><td>".$row["persoane"]."</td><td>".$row["mp"]."</td><td>".$row["retim"]."</td><td>".$row["incalzire"]."</td><td>".$row["apacaldamc"]."</td><td>".$row["apacaldalei"]."</td><td>".$row["apacaldadif"]."</td><td>".$row["aparecemc"]."</td><td>".$row["aparecelei"]."</td><td>".$row["aparecedif"]."</td><td>".$row["curent"]."</td><td>".$row["gaz"]."</td><td>".$row["administrator"]."</td><td>".$row["cheltuieliadministrare"]."</td><td>".$row["acoperis"]."</td><td>".$row["timp"]."</td></tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
}
```

But I get:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Indeed $databaseOject is not a object, it's a array of object, probably that's why I get that error, but how I can make the table in my case - array of objects ? Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The result of `$query->result()` is an array of StdObjects, you can loop through them using a simple `foreach` loop.
To access their properties, as they are stdObjects and not array, you need to replace `$row['id']` with `$row->id`, or replace `result()` with `result_array()`

I strongly advise you to read the doc on the subject [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you should understand that result helper function for `num_rows()` should be implemented before the query `result()` like below:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM consum WHERE timp BETWEEN '".$fromDate."' AND '".$toDate."'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);


if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $databaseObject = $query->result();
}
```

So you can check either the result was existed or not before fetch it.

For your references:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Hope it helps!